# importError: cannot import name 'Voice

Tags: voice

```
from googlevoice import Voice
from googlevoice.util import input

voice = Voice()
voice.login()

outgoingNumber = input('Number to call: ')
forwardingNumber = input('Number to call from [optional]: ') or None

voice.call(outgoingNumber, forwardingNumber)

if input('Calling now... cancel?[y/N] ').lower() == 'y':
    voice.cancel(outgoingNumber, forwardingNumber)
```

File "/Users/craiglavallee/Downloads/googlevoice.py", line 1, in 
    from googlevoice import Voice

Comment: improved readability

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include context to your source code in order to receive the proper responses. Please check the documentation [on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello World")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()

Comment: import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello World")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()  --- NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined